# Abnormally high interrupt time

Tags: windows-8.1, interrupts

I have a new Windows 8.1 box, and in task manager I have an abnormal high CPU usage by `System Interrupts` (10% - 25% on a dual core i3). What could be the cause and how can I troubleshoot this problem ?

I already disconnected all unnecessary system components (PCI card, touch screen).

Another related symptom is that my printer (connected on a serial port) is printing deliberately rubbish, even though there is no job printing.

Comment: What tools are you using to deermine this?

Comment: I did not use any tool. I simply look in the `Processes` tab of `Task Manager`

Comment: @Ramhound Is there a tool that you could recommend ?

Comment: trace it with xperf: http://www.msfn.org/board/index.php?showtopic=140263

Comment: **I am not interested in doing recomendations before I know which tools you have used.**

Comment: @ramhound As I told in the question and in the comment, I'm using Taskmanager.

Comment: But how did you determine they are system interrupts?

Comment: @ramhound Taskmanager labels them as such.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The culprit was the HDMI connection. While the screen was connected as HDMI, the system was flooded by interrupts. After connecting the screen with a VGA cable, everything was normal again.